# How can a vector name be treated as an array name?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Firstly I am new to C++ so may be the question is stupid !!
Secondly I have already seen the related answers to this and can conclude that name of a vector could be treated as an array.

```
vector <int> myVector(7,10);   // creates a vector of size 7 and initializes with 10
```

We may use the name myVector as an array and write like myVector[0], myVector[1]...

But since vector is a class and myVector is it's object  there should be storage area inside that object which could be treated as an array like myVector.someArray[0], myVector.someArray[1] not the object name itself how does that become possible?

Comment: Okay, first forget Java. In C++ we have overloaded operators that are actually syntactic aliases for functions. The [] is such an operator.

Comment: Are you thinking of `myVector.data()`? The `data` method gets you a pointer to the vectors internal storage area.

Comment: Nitpick: `std::vector` is not a class. It's a class template. `std::vector<int>` is a class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: Here's a very simple example: https://godbolt.org/z/N4dDsz

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis : So the [] operator is overloaded and internally the array is accessed ?

Comment: Yes, it calls an internal function.

Comment: The link @Mat shared is pretty good.

Comment: Nitpick: in C++ basically everything that has a type is an object, including `int`, arrays and pointers. The only things that aren't are references and functions.

Comment: @Kush yes, `std::vector` overloads `operator[]` to access the internal array

Comment: Thanks All :) I got it

Answer (score 0):

very simple, overloaded operators:

[operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

When you define in your class these kinds of methods, you get to use those special operators; the ones which already can be used with primitive data types as the standard describes.

In case of vector you have something like

```
...

const Element& operator[](const unsigned int index)
{
     return internalArray[index];
}

...
```

within its class declaration.

Something similar you will find in the `std::vector` class, so you can even build your own vector class if you'd like to do that.

For clarification, if a class has the `[]-Operator` defined, you can do something like this with its object:

```
vec[4];
```

which is equivalent to:

```
vec.operator[](4);
```

That also means the parameter of the overloaded operator can be chosen. You could even pass a string to the `[]` operator.

For example `std::map` does that very nicely:

[std::map -> Check out the example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: You [should probably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/4850111) provide a `const Element& operator[]` too.

Comment: @nada: Though not required, in this case better to do also for the parameter, you are right. Thank you!